# Hiding a search container through escape button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did this function to hide search container by escaping button but there is a problem. 
`.spr-container` `.sprsearch-form` and `ico search` is hiding automatically after pressing the escape button.
How to make it still active without hiding again?

CODE :

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) { 
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      $('#sp_search_pro_1').slideToggle('fast');
      $('#spr-container').slideToggle();
      $('#sp_searchpro').slideToggle();
      $('#top1e_content_result').slideToggle();
      $('#suggest-list').slideToggle();
        if($('.spr-container .sprsearch-form').hasClass('active_form')) {
          $('.spr-container .sprsearch-form').removeClass('active_form');
        }
      }
    else {
        $('.spr-container .sprsearch-form').addClass('active_form');
    }

    if ($('.icon-search').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.icon-search').removeClass('active');
     } 
     else {
        $('.icon-search').addClass('active');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Please give a little more description about the problemi you have

Comment: i have search icon with icon-search class name, when i use the escape button during the search container visible it has to show up.

Answer (score 0):

In your if  conditions your removing classes. Only.   Using hide show respectively  withing the conditions

Where the is add class. Chain hide or show methods

$('.spr-container .sprsearch-form').addClass('active_form').show();

Where there is remove class

.hide()

> assuming you don't have a display none on elements without a class

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but even with that using hide and show methods does not work.  I do not know where is the problem here is not showing the search button again after the escape event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with another way to make it direct for hide the search button.

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 27) {


         if($('.spr-container .sprsearch-form').hasClass('active_form')){
                        $('.spr-container .sprsearch-form').removeClass('active_form');
           }


  if($('.icon-search').hasClass('active')){
                        $('.icon-search').removeClass('active');

} 
});
```